# "Error formatting string" when using variable from string replacement in PowerShell DSC

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, foreach, dsc

I'm trying to set up replication in RavenDB by using PowerShell DSC, but I get this error in the `TestScript` scriptblock when I try to compile the configuration:

> PSDesiredStateConfiguration\Node : Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format.

Here is my scriptblock:

```
TestScript = {
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET "http://localhost:8080/Databases/Test/Docs/Raven/Replication/Destinations" -UseBasicParsing

    $ravenSlaves = "{0}".Split(",")

    foreach($ravenSlave in $ravenSlaves)
    {
        if($result -notmatch $ravenSlave)
        {
            return $false
        }
    }

    return $true
} -f ($Node.RavenSlaves)
```

And `RavenSlaves` is defined like a string in my ConfigurationData for the nodes like this:

```
@{
    NodeName = "localhost"
    WebApplication   =   "test"            
    Role = "Master server"
    RavenSlaves = "server1,server2"
}
```

The problem seems to be connected to when I'm using the `foreach` to iterate over the `$ravenSlaves` variable, because if I remove the `foreach` (and the `if` inside the `foreach`) the configuration compiles and the mof file is created.

Comment: this -- "{0}".Split(",")   needs the -f format operator

Comment: @Kiran, yes? Isn't that what I have done? If you look at the script-block i provided in the question I have specified "-f ($Node.RavenSlaves)" at the end of the script. Isn't that correct?

Comment: ok didnt see the dsc part of the question....the script resource in dsc is a string and allows you to use values defined outside using the $using modifier so perhaps you need to import ur hashtable into the test resource as $using:myhashtable then do the split on the ravenslaves key

Comment: @Kiran, thank you. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kiran led me to the right solution by his comment about using the `$using` modifier in the configuration.

I edited the `RavenSlaves` property on the node to be an array like this:

```
@{
   NodeName = "localhost"
   WebApplication   =   "test"            
   Role = "Master server"
   RavenSlaves = @("server1,server2")
}
```

And then I changed the `TestScript`-block to be like this:

```
TestScript = {
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET "http://localhost:8080/Databases/Test/Docs/Raven/Replication/Destinations" -UseBasicParsing

    $ravenSlaves = $Node.RavenSlaves

    foreach($ravenSlave in $using:ravenSlaves)
    {
        if($result -notmatch $ravenSlave)
        {
            return $false
        }
    }  

    return $true

}
```

The script compiled and ran on the server and the replication document in RavenDB was correct.

Comment: grt...the $ravenslaves should be  $using:node.ravenslaves... then you can iterate using foreach on $ravenslaves instead of $using:ravenslaves

Comment: Thanks @Kiran! I guess that's a better approach to make it more readable and to avoid having $using several places if you're using the variable several places in the configuration for that one node. But does it have some other advantages as well?